# Disable a specific Chrome extension for a specific page?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Can I add code to a page that will disable an extension running on that specific page?

Yes, there are extensions and settings that will prevent an extension from running.

I'm trying to avoid those approaches and control it within the page itself where I don't want it to run.

Yes, I can add code to the page(s) where I want to disable.

Want to do this with Javasript or JQuery.

Comment: Are you trying to prevent an extension you wrote to not run on a certain page or are you attempting to disable all of one of your users content scripts on a page?

Comment: @megawac Thanks. I do have access to the CRX code and know how to disable it for sites or pages. I want the capability to add a block to specific pages without changing the CRX code. Hope this answers your question.

Comment: @megawac If needed, I could do a one-time change to the CRX to enable this to function. Now that I think more about that approach, perhaps the page block just sets something in localStorage?

Comment: The way I would do this is just place a custom `meta` tag in the head which tell your extension not to run on this page. Just update your extension to check for the tag

Comment: @megawac Thanks. Haven't done much with meta tags but sounds reasonable and will investigate. Either way will work and will try both. Often seems simply asking the question triggers the obvious simple answers.